# How do I use a document class in ShareLaTeX?

Tags: document-classes, thesis, sharelatex

So my plan was to help a friend to write her thesis in LaTeX instead of Word. The problem is that the university want them to use their template if writing in LaTeX. I have never done something like this on before and having trouble compiling and getting the document class zip and example to both be added into the ShareLaTeX workspace.

How do I do this? It basically is two zip files where one contain example on how to structure and use it and the other one a document class. The link to the files can be found [here](http://www.control.isy.liu.se/student/exjobb/liuthesis/liuthesis.html).

Comment: Wellcome to the community! Your problem is about using Sharelatex or about using the documentclass for your document?

Comment: Yes it is, I have been trying to get it to work for a long time but can not make it even compile. Edit: Thank you btw

Comment: Could you add a minimum working example in your question? It would make answering your question easier.

Comment: It is my understanding that when you upload a zip there, ShareLatex immediately tries to process it. That might not always work. So if it immediately fails, try re-processing 9without re-upload). Also, be sure that you have choose the correct compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Load the `.zip` file with the example (in your case `rtthesisex-exjobb.zip`, don't worry if it doesn't compile at the beginning)
2. unzip the `.zip` file with the `.cls` on your computer (in your case,  `rtthesis.zip`)
3. click on the symbol "Load" (see the red arrow here: [image])
4. Load *all* the files from the unzip of point 2. (you could select them all at once)
5. Click on `main.tex` to make it appear in the code frame.
6. Compile it.

This is the result:
https://it.sharelatex.com/2222726995krhgjrftbsqk.